# How to subscribe to PublishRelay from generic observable?

Tags: generics, rx-swift, rx-cocoa, rx-kotlin

**Kotlin Code:**

```kotlin
fun <T> Observable<T>.circuitBreaker(): Observable<T> {
  val relay = PublishRelay.create<T>()
  this.subscribe(relay)
  return relay.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST).toObservable()
}
```

Above is a Kotlin code which I'm trying to convert into Swift. But, I'm facing an error saying **Cannot convert value of type 'PublishRelay' to expected argument type '(Event<_>) -> Void'**

**Swift Code:**

```swift
extension Observable {
  func circuitBreaker<T>() -> Observable<T> {
    let relay = PublishRelay<T>()
    self.subscribe(relay)
    return relay.asObservable()
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using below:

```
extension Observable {
  func circuitBreaker<T>() -> Observable<T> {
    let relay = PublishSubject<T>()
    _ = self.subscribe { (event: Event<Element>) in
      if let event = event as? Event<T> { relay.on(event) }
    }
    return relay.asObservable()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind and `Observable` to `Relay`. See related discussion [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/pull/1470).